# Can I use the Chrome Web Store in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Can I use the Chrome Web Store in Chromium? Or do I have to install Chrome for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the Chrome Web Store here : http://chrome.google.com/webstore .
But if you want to install the apps, you have to get Chrome/ium 8 or greater. Their icons will show up on the "New tab" page.

Comment: On my system the Store offers the "Add to Chrome" when using Google Chrome, but only "Available in Chrome" when using Chromium

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the chrome web store in chromium.

Chrome web store is nothing special or new it just contains the extensions(it just has option of paid extensions) and themes

Comment: It also has web apps--which are just websites, except you can tie them to the browser a bit more closely.

Answer (score 0):

The web store just redirects to https://chrome.google.com/extensions currently. I don't have Chromium installed to test, but presume you can install these extensions.